# All file text in hexa when open folder in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: sublimetext

I can work well in Sublime text when I open a single file. However, when I want to open a folder, all the files in that folder will be shown in Hexa and the file name will change to ._filename.

[image]

Comment: Open Terminal, navigate to the folder, and enter `cat ._autoload.php`. Does it display the text or is it in binary? Is there a file named `autoload.php` in that folder? Is it text or binary?

Comment: If the files are binary, try `file ._autoload.php` or any other file name to determine if it has been encoded as a specific file type or using a specific encoding.

Comment: If a file is predominantly text but has enough control characters in it, the heuristic in Sublime will consider it to be binary and use this encoding. That said, even if this file is a UTF-32 encoded file, there are an awful lot of null bytes being displayed that makes it seem sketchy that it is in fact text and not binary. Does it open in Notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file with a different encoding. You can do so using "File > Reopen with Encoding" or put "show_encoding": true in user settings and restart to view the encodings and choose the right one.

Comment: I did, unfortunately, it does not work.